# Invoke Calling from Fulfilment Webhook response

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have a contact app, I created an Action Project which eventually decide a number to call based on user conversation. The number to call is being decided at `backend (Fullfilment using Webhook)`.

I want to start call on number being decided at backend(As it is when you say 'Call 55555555' in Google Assistant).

I am not able to find any document on how to start a call using response from Fullfilment.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically start a phone call with Actions on Google.